# How to dismiss a view controller opened with presentModalViewController:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I presented a view controller using `presentModalViewController:`, now how to close/dismiss it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two choices, both involves using dismissModalViewController.

The preferred way is to use delegation and tell the view controller who was responsible for presenting the view to dismiss it. The other way is to have the view who was presented to dismiss itself (which actually asks the parent to dismiss it.)

Answer (score 28):

For iOS6 use this code

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
```

instead of

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This may help you.

Comment: Man you are super duper amazing, i've been searching for like 5 hrs.

Answer (score 22):

From the controller presented modally:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Technically that's not correct, it should be `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`. But for convenience, `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` will automatically forward the message to the parent if the target isn't modally presenting a view controller.