# Close Child View from Parent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

For some reason when I close my child view it causes an error with my webview (in the parent view). The call I am using to close the child view: *(I don't know if this is the right way to do it)*

> `[normalSplashScreen_vc closeNormalSplashScreen];`

Gives me the following error:

> Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...

I can't figure out why closing a child view effects the underlying webview?

*(I think by calling the `closeNormalSplashScreen` function I am closing the main view even though it is called in the child view* - if this is the case how do I remedy this problem?)

---

### Main View

```
@interface turfplusViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet splashScreen *FirstRunsplashScreen_vc;
    IBOutlet NormalSplashScreen *normalSplashScreen_vc;
    IBOutlet UIWebView *Webview;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) splashScreen *FirstRunsplashScreen_vc;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NormalSplashScreen *normalSplashScreen_vc;

// Obviously these functions are declared correctly but for the sake of space

 - (void) displayFirstRunSplashScreen { 
    [self presentModalViewController:FirstRunsplashScreen_vc animated:NO];
}

- (void) displayNormalSplashScreen {
    [self presentModalViewController:normalSplashScreen_vc animated:NO];
}
```

### SplashScreen

The Two splash screens are essentially the same (with the firstRun one having a progress bar).

```
@interface NormalSplashScreen : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *NormalActivityIndicator;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *NormalActivityIndicator;

// Obviously these functions are declared correctly but for the sake of space

- (void) closeNormalSplashScreen {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156791/how-to-close-the-view-which-opened-by-presentmodalviewcontroller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436458/dismiss-childview-from-parentviewcontroller) question. (The second one doesn't answer the question... is it possible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually shows up when you do a UI operation from a thread which is not the main thread.

Where are you calling the method closeNormalSplashScreen from? Is it being called from a different thread than the main thread?

Try doing this and see if the error still comes up

```
[normalSplashScreen_vc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(closeNormalSplashScreen) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; //last argument will change depending on your requirement
```